# Splunk query to find previous requests from different ip

Tags: splunk

Suppose I've got the following log entries:

```
timestamp     ip      path
1668603956000 1.1.1.1 /some/path
1668603955000 2.2.2.2 /some/path
1668603954000 2.2.2.2 /some/other/path
1668603953000 3.3.3.3 /some/path
1668603952000 3.3.3.3 /some/other/path
1668603951000 4.4.4.4 /some/path
1668603950000 5.5.5.5 /some/path
```

I want to end up with a table that shows for `ip=2.2.2.2`, the `ip` from the previous request to the same path but with a different IP.

Expected results:

```
L.time           R.time           R.ip       R.path
1668603954200    1668603954400    3.3.3.3    /some/path
1668603954300    1668603954600    4.4.4.4    /some/other/path
```

What I've tried:

```
source=my_log
| where ip = "2.2.2.2"
| table path, ip, _time
| join type=inner left=L right=R usetime=true earlier=true where L.path = R.path [
    | where L.ip != R.ip
]
| table L._time, R._time, R.ip, R.path
```

But this does not give me any tabular results. I get raw events back, but the `join` doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I'm surprised Splunk didn't throw an error about the stray `and` keyword in the `join` command.  AIUI, the `where` clause is a simple equality that tells Splunk which fields to compare.  The `left` and `right` aliases are for use in the `where` clause and are not available in the subsearch.

Comment: fwiw ... those timestamps aren't in *compliant* Unix epoch format - they're 1000x too big :)

Comment: Sorry, I edited afterward and probably forgot to remove the `and`.

Answer (score 1):

You *seem* to be trying to write SQL, but in SPL

I suggest starting here for how to change your approach - https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/SQLtoSplunk

That said, I believe this will get you toward your goal:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp ip=* path=*
| fields path ip _time
| fields - _raw
| sort 0 path -_time +ip
| streamstats reset_on_change=true current=true latest(_time) as tick by path ip
| eval tick=strftime(tick,"%c")
| stats count by path ip tick
| fields - count
```

Comment: I wouldn't say I was trying to write SQL in SPL, I thought the `join` clause was a legitimate attempt. :) Can you explain why there are two `fields` directives, can they not be combined?

Comment: I always seperate my `fields` calls for clarity - one to remove, and one to keep. `join` *is* valid, but it has a *lot* of limitations, and so tends to be undesirable :)

Comment: Using `join` was also extremely slow. I'll try your suggestion next week